# C Pthreads: Load balacing issues when reading from a file

Tags: c, multithreading, io, pthreads

Im using a simple thread safe queue of tasks, that can be seen in this post : [C Pthreads - issues with thread-safe queue implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914822/c-pthreads-issues-with-thread-safe-queue-implementation)

When the program was only about loading the queue with a bunch of  tasks and performing them concurrently,  the cpu usage was well distributed between all cores as shown by htop and the monitoring system (60 ~ 70% for each core).

When i added some heavy file reading (sequentially) at the beginning of the code, and executed the exact same parallel tasks, the cpu usage got concentrated in one of the cores (100%) during all execution. Can someone help me figure out what is happening?  Thanks.

Comment: You could have a [mcve] in **this** question because you just write your thread management in the other. Maybe, there is only one thread than consume 100% of one CPU because it has a lot to work? With htop, you could see what thread consumes CPU.

Comment: @Stargateu I'm asking more of a generic question that's why i didn't add the code, but i will try to do it. It's not that only one thread is consuming 100%. There's only one cpu beeing used (at 100%) when i add file reading to the code.